# Find methods mango + node.js access values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Return always an undefined value (here user.password). I really don't undestand why

```
var userModel = restful.model('user');
userModel.find({email:req.params.email}, function(err, user){
    if (user.length){
      console.log(user); // WORKS WELL. I see whole object
      console.log(user.password); // Retuns undefined
      res.render(viewPath + "accountVerified", { meta: meta, success:1});
    }
});
```

Comment: Your `user` has no `password` variable. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading multiple records from db, but trying to access variable from array. See edited code:

```
var userModel = restful.model('user');
userModel.find({email:req.params.email}, function(err, users){
    if (users.length) {
      console.log(users); // WORKS WELL. I see whole object
      console.log(users[0].password); // Retuns undefined
      res.render(viewPath + "accountVerified", { meta: meta, success:1});
    }
});
```

Comment: Your user object has no variable `password`, simple as that.

Comment: I've edited answer. Please learn JS and identify issues specifically to topics. This is nothing to do with mongo, it relates to JS.